# Powershell - DataTable Load data one row at a time

Tags: sql-server, oracle, powershell, datatable

There is a pair of identical databases with 80 tables each: source (Oracle) and target (SQL Server).

There is a Powershell 7.x script that processes the data: it reads a table from the source, does some simple processing in a local `DataTable` variable and writes results to the target. Rinse, repeat x 80.

The source is read using `System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection` and the target is populated with `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy`

79 of tables are relatively small and fit entirely in memory, so I am loading them using the `System.Data.DataTable.Load()` method.

1 table, however, is very large horizontally (each record contains a dozen of megabytes XML clob) and needs to be processed row-by-row i.e. a single row loaded from source, processed, written to target.

The question is: how can I loop through individual records from a `System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection` dataset, and pull them to a local `DataTable` object? I was looking at the `System.Data.DataTable.LoadDataRow()` method but it doesn't seem to be doing what I need here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of loading a DataTable, just call ExecuteReader, and pass the DataReader to [SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.writetoserver?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-data-sqlclient-sqlbulkcopy-writetoserver(system-data-idatareader)).

If you want to use LoadDataRow, still use ExecuteReader, and while rdr.Read() use [rdr.GetValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getvalues?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) to copy the row into an object array, which you can pass to LoadDataRow.

Comment: Didn't know about rdr.GetValues - good to learn something new! Your answer, while correct, didn't work for me though and I ended up writing a custom loop processing one row at a time (based on PK). It is a bit slower (one ExecuteReader per row) but gets me the right results so I'm good.